# TypeScript function calls and returning data

Tags: function, typescript, ionic-framework

I am learning Ionic and I have the following function:

```
loadPaper(paper){
  this.testFunc();

    console.log('questions', this.questions);
    console.log('paper', paper);

    this.navCtrl.push(this.loadPaperPage, {
        paper: paper,
        questions: this.questions
    });

}

testFunc(){
  this.papersData.getPaper().subscribe(questions => {
    this.questions = questions.questions;
  });
}
```

My loadPaper function calls `testFunc()` in order to setup a global variable with required data. I then attempt to use the data in a `console.log` print but the console reports the data is `undefined` instead of the json data I was expecting.

Aside from the fact it does not work, I am sure it's not the best solution. I did try my preferred and standard solution of `return`ing data from the second function but that failed to work.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you share code for `getPaper` method as well?

Answer (score 1):

`testFunc` doesn't save a subscription and doesn't return an observable. Using `subscribe` in asynchronous function that is supposed to be chained can be considered antipattern.

`testFunc` can be modified to return an observable instead, and its caller is responsibile for subscribing it:

```
testFunc(){
  return this.papersData.getPaper().do(questions => {
    this.questions = questions.questions;
  });
}

loadPaper(paper){
  return this.testFunc().subscribe(questions => {...});
}
```

If `this.questions` isn't used anywhere else, there may be no need for `do` at all. if `loadPaper` is chained somewhere else, it may have same problem as `testFunc` before with returning a subscription instead of an observable.

If `getPaper` returns completed observable, it's may be beneficial to switch to promises as soon as possible, particularly because `async..await` can be used:

```
testFunc(){
  return this.papersData.getPaper().toPromise();
}

async loadPaper(paper){
  const questions = await this.testFunc();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.papersData.getPaper().subscribe` subscribes to an observable. The function declared in the subscription block is called asynchronous and only when the observable emits a value. You can't know when the observable emits a value. So it can be (and is) later then the execution of `console.log('questions', this.questions);`. So the value of `this.questions` is not set at the moment of this execution.

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
  this.subscription = this.papersData.getPaper().subscribe(questions => {
    this.questions = questions.questions;
    let paper = <whatever>;
    this.loadPaper(paper);
  });
}

ionViewWillUnload(){
  if (this.subscription instanceof Subscription) {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}

loadPaper(paper){

    console.log('questions', this.questions);
    console.log('paper', paper);

    this.navCtrl.push(this.loadPaperPage, {
        paper: paper,
        questions: this.questions
    });

}
```

perhaps you don't want that loadPaper is called directly when the page is loaded. Then you can tune the Observable to wait for another event (click on page, mousemove etc.)

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
  this.subscription = Observalbe.combineLatest(this.papersData.getPaper(), this.clickEvent).subscribe(data => {
    let questions = data[0];
    let clickEvent = data[1];
    this.questions = questions.questions;
    let paper = <whatever>;
    this.loadPaper(paper);
  });
}
```

To use javascript/typescript for a bigger project you have to learn how asynchronous (Callback/Promise/Observable) work. The subscription and observables are part of [rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/).